# How to Bind Two Lists to Two Columns of Wpf DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

I want to bind two lists to two columns of a Wpf DataGrid. How is this done in Xaml?

```
Class MainWindow 

    Public Property Column1 As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3}
    Public Property Column2 As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer) From {4, 5, 6}

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) them :

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Column1 _
                        .Zip(Column2, _
                             Function(c1, c2) New With { .Column1 = c1, .Column2 = c2 })
```

XAML

```
...
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}" />
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You create a new list which merges data from the two lists into one and use the merged list as source for the datagrid.