# Predicate to zip two collections and use as binding source

Tags: wpf, collections, binding, predicate

I've got two collections, `ObservableCollection<Lap>` and a `ObservableCollection<Racer>` where `Lap` holds lap data of a car race and `Racer`, you guess it, the Racer's data. Both objects know the `racerId`.

Is there a way I can come up with a predicate to use that as a `Zip`-func to zip those two collections together? The reason I want to do that is to bind them `DataGrid`.

I had seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908185/how-to-bind-two-lists-to-two-columns-of-wpf-datagrid), but can't quite see how to use it with a predicate.

I came up with that:

```
laps.Zip(participants, (lap, racer) => lap.EnrollmentId == racer.EnrollmentId);
```

But how would I map that to the DataGridColumns?

Comment: Should the result be observable too?

Comment: I think it should. But it's supposed to be an expression used as binding context for a `DataGrid`. Is it necessary then?

Comment: That depends. Do you want to add or remove items from the collections while showing them? If yes, observable is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `Join` instead, since you do want to combine the properties of both based on a matching Id. For `Zip()` to work both collections must have the same number of entries in the same matching order already.

```
var results = from racer in participants
              join l in laps
              on racer.EnrollmentId equals l.EnrollmentId
              select new 
              {
                //select the properties you are interested in here
                //or just use both:
                Racer = racer, 
                Lap = l
              }
```

Comment: Note that zip doesn't require the same number of entries, so for example, the last few racers might not have any lat associated with them. But it would still require matching order for those who do.

Comment: Is the resulting collection capable of being a databound source (`ItemSource` in this case)? Couldn't get that working yet.